# remove a subclass and add another class at a time

Tags: javascript

**css file**

```
.clsA { ... }
.clsB { ... }
.clsC { ... }
...
...
```

**js file**

```
var g = $('.gHead')

var res, last_key=''
var ca, cb, cc, cd, ....

ca = $('.clsA')
cb = $('.clsA')
cc = $('.clsA')
...
...

function nextV(a) {
    var len = a.length
    var choice = Math.floor(Math.random() * len) /* problem 1 */

    res = a.filter(function (elm) {
        return elm.key == a[choice].key
    })
    g.removeClass(res[0].key) /* problem 2 */
    last_key = res[0].key /* got key */
}

function changeIt() {
    var arr = []
    arr.push({key: 'ca', value: ca})
    arr.push({key: 'cb', value: cb})
    ...
    ...

    nextV(arr)

    if (res.length > 0) {
        g.addClass(res[0].key) /* working */
        console.log(g)
    }

    console.log('prevClass: '+ last_key) /* found prev added item */
}

$('.cng').on('click', function () {
    changeIt()
})
```

I want `.gHead` must attach only one class per click of that `.cng`. Like: `.gHead .clsA` on next click it should be `.gHead .clsB` and so on. But, I got: `.gHead .clsA` >> `.gHead .clsA .clsB` >> `.gHead .clsA .clsB .clsC`

**problem 1:**
*Instead of a RandomChoice, I want to make it a LinearChoice, based on that array `arr` indexes. But, I don't want to use `arr.indexOf()`.*

**problem 2:**
*It --> `g.removeClass(res[0].key)` has no effect on the output. Where almost the same opposite g.addClass(...) is working!*

Comment: What does *"make it a linear choice"* mean?

Comment: @charlietfl I want to say:  "let array `arr` has 10 elements, random indexes means 0, 3, 8, 1 ,9 ,2 ... whereas linear indexes are 0, 1, 2, 3 ... I want to do that way..", <-- LinearChoice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cleaned up your code a bit, here you can see that removing the class does not work as you are adding it back immediately after returning from `nextV()`.

**js file**

```
var g = $('.gHead')

var ca, cb, cc, cd, ....

ca = $('.clsA')
cb = $('.clsA')
cc = $('.clsA')
...
...

var arr = [] // does not make sense to always recreate this
arr.push({key: 'ca', value: ca})
arr.push({key: 'cb', value: cb})
    ...

var choice = 0

function nextV() {
    choice = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length) /* problem 1 */
    // the filtering always leads to res being a single item array and res[0] being a[choice]
    g.removeClass(arr[choice].key) /* problem 2 */
}

function changeIt() {
    nextV()

    // if (res.length > 0) { // this is always true in your code
    g.addClass(arr[choice].key) /* working */
}

$('.cng').on('click', function () {
    changeIt()
})
```

To walk through the keys linearly, you could initialize `choice` to `arr.length-1` instead of zero and calculate choice as `choice = (choice+1) % a.length` in `nextV` instead of the random function.

Then you can also remove the previous class before adding the new one (which i think is what you want to do, "problem 2") using `g.removeClass(arr[(choice+arr.length-1)%arr.length].key)`

To conclude: From what you are describing, i'm not sure your code results in what you expect from it, but I hope this helps you to figure it out correctly.

Comment: thanks ... ✌️️ it's working! I've not tried with modulo division, & for the idea of `removeClass(arr[(choice+arr.length-1)%arr.length].key)`, where I was trying other ways, as such: `g.removeClass(g.siblings(arr[choice].key)`

Answer (score 0):

You could store previous class on the element using [`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) and retrieve it for removal on next click

Since you haven't provided enough markup for a full example here's a basic example

```js
const classes = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

function changeIt () {
  const $el = $(this),
    prevIndex = $el.data('prev'),
    // add one or go back to zero
    nextIndex = prevIndex + 1 < classes.length ? prevIndex + 1 : 0;

  if (prevIndex > -1) {
    // remove if previous exists
    $el.removeClass(classes[prevIndex])
  }
 // add the next class and store index on element
  $el.addClass(classes[nextIndex])
     .data('prev', nextIndex)

}

$('li').click(changeIt)
       .data('prev', -1)// initialize element data
```

```css
.a{ color:red}
.b{color:blue}
.c{color:green}
li{padding:.5em}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>Click to change class</li>
  <li>Click to change class</li>
  <li>Click to change class</li>
  <li>Click to change class</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: yes, it's another good solution but I want to stick with [@Beppo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2035513/beppo)'s answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change css classes on ONE element ( as charlietfl pointed out ) based on an array, do something like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <style>
          .gHead {
            width: 100px; height:100px;
          }
          .clsA {
            background: #000;
          }
          .clsB {
            background: #f00;
          }
          .clsC {
            background: #0f0;
          }
          .clsD {
            background: #00f;
          }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="gHead clsA">
          Head
        </div>
        <script>
          var styles = ['clsA', 'clsB', 'clsC', 'clsD']
          var currentStyle = 0
          var gHead = document.querySelector('.gHead')

            function changeStyle () {

              if(currentStyle < styles.length - 1){

                currentStyle++
                gHead.classList.remove(styles[currentStyle-1])

              }else{

                currentStyle = 0
                gHead.classList.remove(styles[styles.length-1])
              }
              gHead.classList.add(styles[currentStyle])
            }
        </script>
        <button onClick="changeStyle()">change style</button>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Won't work if there is more than one element involved

Answer (score 0):

You can use this if you have several elements with class .gHead

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <style>
          .gHead {
            width: 100px; height:100px;
          }
          .clsA {
            background: #000;
          }
          .clsB {
            background: #f00;
          }
          .clsC {
            background: #0f0;
          }
          .clsD {
            background: #00f;
          }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="gHead clsA">
          Head
        </div>

        <div class="gHead clsA">
          Head
        </div>

        <div class="gHead clsA">
          Head
        </div>
        <script>
          var styles = ['clsA', 'clsB', 'clsC', 'clsD']
          var currentStyle = 0
          var gHead = document.querySelectorAll('.gHead')
          function remove(x, reset) {
            reset ? x.classList.remove(styles[styles.length-1]) : x.classList.remove(styles[currentStyle-1])
          }
          function add(x) {
            x.classList.add(styles[currentStyle])
          }
          function newStyle () {

            if(currentStyle < styles.length - 1){

              currentStyle++

              for(var i = 0; i < gHead.length; i++){
                remove(gHead[i], 0)
                add(gHead[i])
              }

            }else{

              currentStyle = 0
              for(var i = 0; i < gHead.length; i++){
                remove(gHead[i], 1)
                add(gHead[i])
              }
            }

          }
        </script>
        <button onClick="newStyle()"></button>
      </body>
    </html>
```